# Is there a way to label a layer using its file name or layer name?

Tags: qgis, labeling

Is there a way to label a layer using its file name or layer name (if I'd change it in Layers window TOC)?
I tried some functions but I'm not good on that.

I have lots of shapes (lines) and it would be easy to identify them this way. Of course, this name could be a table attribute but I'm trying a alternative way (maybe more dynamic).

Comment: Very good question but I do not think it is supported (yet). You could request this as a new feature [here](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis) by registering and posting a new request form.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since QGIS 2.12 you can use the following expression to print the layer name:

```sql
layer_property( @layer_id, 'name')
```

You can lookup further properties in the documentation of the `layer_property` function in the expression editor.

Answer (score 3):

Bonus answer: if you try `layer_property( @layer_id, 'name')` but your layername is a little bit long to work as a label, you can split that up over multiple lines:

Say your layer name is: `'Gibbs_ID1730544_A9056_TRRS_Harvest'`

You can split it over multiple lines using wordwrap like this:
`wordwrap(layer_property( @layer_id, 'name'), 15, '_')` 
which specifies you want to get the layername, split it on the _ character and keep each line to a max of 15 characters long.

The result: you get these four strings over four lines:

`Gibbs`
`ID1730544`
`A9056`
`TRRS_Harvest`